# What is それ doing in this sentence

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In reading exercise #3 of JLPT N3 読む guide, there's a sentence that contains **それ** and I don't understand why.

> 大好きなおもちゃが壊れてしまった子供にとっては、**それ**を直してくれるおもちゃの専門家が、神様のように見えるようです。

Can someone explain to me why **それ** is being used?

Comment: Are you asking what the それ refers to, or why それ is used over これ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a pronoun which refers to `おもちゃ` and is `直してくれる`'s object; as far as I understand, the breakdown is `それを直してくれる` (to fix that [toy]) and `おもちゃの専門家` (toy expert), giving "The toy expert who fixes that [toy]".

Comment: 説明してありがとうございます。